# Menu com pushbutton arduino (esp32)

Tags: c, menu, arduino, button

Tenho uma dúvida sobre a construção de um menu com botões.
Inicialmente, tenho que esperar um botão ser pressionado.
Quando alguém sai, tenho que abrir a opção do botão pressionado. Tentei o seguinte, mas não tive sucesso. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

```
void loop()
{
    int button1 = digitalRead(but1);
    int button2 = digitalRead(but2);

    while(button1 == LOW && button2 ==LOW){};
    while(button1 == HIGH || button2 ==HIGH){
        if(button1 == HIGH){
            Serial.print("RFID")
            rfid_menu();
        }

        if(button2 == HIGH){
            Serial.print("FingerPrint")
            fingerprint_menu();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que é só um erro lógico no código.

```
void loop()
{
    int button1 = digitalRead(but1);
    int button2 = digitalRead(but2);

    // esse while esta travando seu programa
    // por que só realiza a leitura dos botão uma vez e utiliza ela para sempre 
    // se nenhum estiver apertado.
    while(button1 == LOW && button2 ==LOW){}; 

    // na verdade ocorre com esse while a mesma coisa, mas se existir algum 
    // botão apertado na primeira execução do loop
    while(button1 == HIGH || button2 ==HIGH){
        if(button1 == HIGH){
            Serial.print("RFID")
            rfid_menu();
        }

        if(button2 == HIGH){
            Serial.print("FingerPrint")
            fingerprint_menu();
        }
    };
}
```

Então se você retirar os dois `while` seu programa deve funcionar do jeito esperado, só com os `if`

Answer (score -3):

```
void check_menu(int botao){

if(botao && 0x02)funcao_rfid(); //bit 1
if(botao && 0x04)funcao_finger(); //bit 2

}

void loop()
{
bool button1 = digitalRead(but1);
bool button2 = digitalRead(but2);

int botoes=(button1 && 0x02) || (button2 && 0x04);
if(button1 == HIGH || button2 ==HIGH)check_menu(botoes);

}
```